# Add release condition on module via desire2learn valence web services

Tags: desire2learn, valence

I am trying to add modules using Desire2Learn's valence API, which also involves setting up a release condition. I am specifically looking for adding this condition Classlist->Group Enrollment on the module. Could not find an API that would add a release condition on a module.
http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/content.html

Has anyone come across with this? What API shall be used for adding a release condition via valence web services?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the Valence Learning Framework APIs do not expose the ability to view or edit release conditions. So while you can create the content modules via Valence, you will have to use the Web UI to manage release conditions.

This sounds like a good candidate for a feature request. Clients of D2L can search and post feature requests to the [Product Ideas Exchange](https://community.desire2learn.com/d2l/lp/navbars/1796/customlinks/external/15394). You're welcome to share the link to the PIE post via the forums to promote it to fellow developers in the Developer Community of Practice: https://community.brightspace.com/devcop.